# How to match two columns with nearest time points?

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe. It is a time series with each observations having values for days 1-4. There is an additional column that shows at which time the test was made in hrs.

```
    dt
Name  values Days   Test  
 a    0.2    1      20
 a    0.3    2      20 
 a    0.6    3      20
 a    0.2    4      20
 b    0.3    1      44
 b    0.4    2      44
 b    0.8    3      44
 b    0.7    4      44
 c    0.2    1      24
 c    0.7    2      24
```

I have to make a time series such that each line represents the subject. 
First I made a plot with days and values, with subjects as colors.

This gave me a line plot for each subject, plotted against days and values. I am happy with it.

However, I have to incorporte when the test was taken on the line plot. I could do it separately at the top or bottom of the plot. But not exactly on the line.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the directlabels package to add the times:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

ggplot(DF, aes(Days, values, color = Name)) + 
     geom_line() +
     geom_dl(aes(label = Test), method = "last.points")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
Name  values Days   Test  
 a    0.2    1      20
 a    0.3    2      20 
 a    0.6    3      20
 a    0.2    4      20
 b    0.3    1      44
 b    0.4    2      44
 b    0.8    3      44
 b    0.7    4      44
 c    0.2    1      24
 c    0.7    2      24"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer!. I would like to plot the "20" on the line corresponding to the exact location like between 1 and 2 using some symbol.